# Any language with syntactic sugar for assign variable if not defined?

Tags: syntax, syntactic-sugar

In almost every language I tend to write something that sets a variable to a default value if it's not defined. Everytime I get surprised why the syntax is not simpler, e.g. why I have to write the variable name twice just to set it to a default value. For example, in Perl:

```
my $var;
# some code here...
$var = "default" unless $var; # $var typed twice
```

Or in C:

```
char *var = NULL;
// some code here...
if (!var)             // var typed
    var = "default";  // twice
```

Why not have some syntactic sugar that sets the variable if it's not defined? In perl it could look like

```
$var ?= "default";
```

I am just curious, are there any languages out there that in fact have syntactic sugar for this?

Comment: I just found syntactic sugar for this in perl: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796470/what-kind-of-syntactic-sugar-is-available-in-perl-to-reduce-code-for-l-rvalue-op

Comment: Note that some of this is due to how variables are implemented in different languages. In compiled languages like C, if a variable exists it has a value (it may be undefined/uninitialized/garbage/trap-inducing/etc., but since it refers to a specific location in memory, it has a value). In languages that implement variables via a dictionary or other lookup-table sort of structure, it is actually possible to have a variable that currently has no value. Many interpreted languages like shells, perl, python, etc. would be more like this.

Answer (score 0):

**bash** supports the parameter expansion and testing.

e.g. if `$1` is defined AND NOT EMPTY, use `$1`; otherwise, set to "text", enter:

```
output=${1-text}
```